# How to display media files stored in Amazon S3 in Django template?

Tags: html, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have integrated Amazon S3 with my Django app. A media folder has been created in my S3 bucket, and when users upload a file it shows up there just fine. What I'm unclear about is how to display these files in the template. Currently the code is:

```
<img src="https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/myprojectbucket/media/{{ model.file }}"/>
```

I've also tried:

```
<img src="{{ model.file }}"/>
```

Another thing to keep in mind is when I try to access these files from the S3 account I get this output. Not sure if this is a permissions issue or what. However, in the admin the image shows up fine.

- No longer getting access denied-I made access public (Not sure if this is the only/best way to do it). Still unclear on how to display it in template. The url gives a 404 error.
- In Admin the file path is /folder/file.jpg, but in the template the file path is /media/folder/file.jpg. I think this could be the source of the problem, but not sure why media is there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604977/url-for-public-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL for public Amazon S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604977/url-for-public-amazon-s3-bucket)

Comment: @RandallHunt The question you link to helps somewhat, but mine is more about how to display it in a Django template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer can also be found at [Getting MEDIA images on Amazon S3 server on template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721079/getting-media-images-on-amazon-s3-server-on-template) so if mods feel this is not needed feel free to delete.

Super simple. All you have to do is:

```
<img src="{{ model.file.url }}"/>
```