# How can i access images stored in my s3 bucket with url in html

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to show uploaded images on my html page with returned/made url.
but i am getting access denied on that url.
I am new to aws s3 how can i fix it.
I want ot access it in both(App and web with that url)

Comment: We need some _code_ to find the issue.

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328695/how-to-display-media-files-stored-in-amazon-s3-in-django-template

Comment: hey I think i have got yhe solution: s3.ObjectAcl(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,'%s/%s' %(AWS_BLOG_IMAGES_FOLDER,file.name)).put(ACL='public-read')

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because of the bucket permission. Looks like your bucket is not public that's why you're getting access denied issue when calling from the webpage. One thing you could do which is secure as well (instead of making your bucket public) is that to upload those images with pre-signed URLs. You can learn more about pre-signed URLs on AWS page [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). Hope this helps.

Also, you need to give more information in your question to get more precise answers.